# How to check if a Server and Client are in the same concurrency model?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, com

The concurrency model can be either **apartment-threaded** or **multi-threaded**

**Question:**

- How to ensure that both the Client and Server **are** operating from within the **same** concurrency model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you *need to* know. Two quick examples:

- Performance hit of proxy/stub pairs is a problem
- You need to pass around "unmarshallable" data or objects

So, the answer -- if you do need to know:

The server and the client must be designed and implemented to support the same or compatible models. Either one of these scenarios will do:

- Both should be MTA, or
- Both should be STA, or
- The server should be "Both" (supports either)
- The Server should be "free-threaded" (but that doesn't buy you anything extra compared to Both, in this scenario)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know, there's something wrong with your design: the client and server need too much information about one another's internals.  Part of the point of client-server is to decouple the two.

That said, then, there is a registry value ThreadingModel.There's an [MSDN article on these things](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809971.aspx) as well.

Comment: Thanks Charlie - I'm having some issues... moreover, I'm new to COM Programming. Kind regards

Comment: NP, the COM model is a little tough going.